# Добавляется лишняя запись в EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Имею несколько моделей.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PreviewText { get; set; }
    public string FullText { get; set; }
    public string ImgSrc { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Комментарий добавляю так

```
public void AddComment(Comment comment, int id, MembershipUser curentUser)
{
    if (comment==null || curentUser==null)
    {
        IsSuccess = false;
    }

    var idUser = (int)curentUser.ProviderUserKey;
    var article = _articleRepository.Find(id);
    comment.User = _userProfileRepository.Find(idUser);

    if (article != null)
    {
        if (article.Comments == null)
        {
            article.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        }
        article.Comments.Add(comment);
        //обертка, над стандартным Entry
        _articleRepository.Entry(article, article);

    }

    _articleRepository.Save();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при добавлении комментария, в БД создается новый пользователь, с именем текущего. 
[image]

В чём может быть проблема? 
В репозитории стандартные CRUD, никакой логики. Проблемы, насколько я понимаю, там быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взгляните в свою реализацию репозитория. Я так понимаю, у вас `_articleRepository` и `_userProfileRepository` используют разные контексты EF. Поэтому пользователь, загруженный из одного репозитория, для второго оказывается новой записью.

Вам надо или переделать репозитории на использование общего контекста (но это потребует пересмотра механизма сохранения изменений) - либо же понадобится явно присоединять пользователя ко второму контексту:

```
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged; // как-то так
```

Вариант номер три - вместо сущности пользователя использовать внешний ключ:

```
comment.UserId = idUser; // в данном случае так получилось даже лучше
```

PS но зачем вы вообще используете репозитории, если там "обычные CRUD операции и никакой логики"? EF и так дает довольно хорошее API, зачем же делать обертку над ним ради самой обертки?